# how to `requests.post` a numpy array

Tags: python, opencv, python-requests

I am trying to send an image returned by opencv .read function to a server. When I import an image using open() everything works fine but sending the frame does not lead to the desired response (seems like the server needs another datatype).
My code is:

```
ret, frame = vid.read()
img_str = cv2.imencode('.jpg', np.array(frame))[1].tobytes() 
rsp = requests.post(url, auth = (user, pwd), files={'img':img_str})
```

This does not return the desired response. Using {'img':open(filename,'rb')}) does return the desired response. I have tried some different things but I don't know how to convert the frame returned by opencv to the datatype open() returns (io.BufferedReader). Does anyone know?
Thanks!

Comment: `assert ret`, you must do your error checking. and look up what different types of data are accepted by `requests.post`.

Comment: The problem is not directly with request.post. It will send the data but the server does not accept it. It does accept the _io.BufferedReader type though. So all I would need to do is convert the frame to this type. But I can't find any way on how to do this without saving the image and reloading it, which is quite ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a numpy array, but not a file-like object, I'd recommend *not* using the `files=...` way to pass your data in.

If you have `bytes` data (a numpy array can turn into that), you pass them in a different way: as the `data=` argument. That is the straightforward way to use `requests.post`.

Arguments are documented here: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.post

Note: `frame` is a numpy array already (in your `imencode` call). "Converting" it to one is superfluous.

```py
success, frame_encoded = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
assert success # always check for errors, at least fail hard

frame_bytes = frame_encoded.tobytes() # numpy array to bytes object

rsp = requests.post(url, ..., data=frame_bytes)
```

I think passing just `data=frame` might work already because numpy arrays implement the python "buffer" protocol, which should be enough for `requests.post`... you should try it.

And don't forget to break your video reading loop `if not ret`.

If you **do** want to keep using `files=...` (and give the file the name `img`), you can construct a file-like object using `io.BytesIO`:

```py
...
import io
frame_file = io.BytesIO(frame) # yes, that is enough

rsp = requests.post(url, ..., files={'img': frame_file}) 
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. As the server needs the name 'img' and simply sending the data does not work I can only try the io.BytesIO() proposal, which I have tried before and of course for sending it with requests.post it works but sadly the server does not accept it and does not send the desired response. I think it was not really a good idea asking this question here, because I don't know what the server exactly needs and therefore it is not solvable for strangers.

Comment: But if someone comes here with a similar problem - it might be worth a try to do the following: 
animage = Image.fromarray(frame)
imagefile = BytesIO()
animage.save(imagefile, format='png')
imagedata = imagefile.getvalue()
now imagedata can be passed as files={'img':imagedata} and for me it works :)!

Comment: if that PIL code works... that would be interesting to investigate, i.e. look at what the BytesIO returns when read from. you could show what the server *did* respond with. show the whole request/response traffic. use wireshark if needed.